# How can I see a list of pages and post where my custom Gutenberg block is used?

Tags: posts, pages, block-editor, deprecation

### Background: Creating Custom Gutenberg Blocks and the Challenges with Breaking Changes

I am new to creating custom Gutenberg blocks (each block is a separate plugin) and have recently ran into the issue of breaking changes when I update the blocks' code. I learned how [block depreciation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-deprecation/) can help solve the issue of breaking code changes, but I still have the challenge of finding the specific pages and posts where these blocks are used.

### Reason for the Question: To Find All Instances of a Custom Gutenberg Block and Speed Up the Quality Control Process

I am looking for a way to see a list of the posts and pages where they have been used so that I can verify that the upgrade path is working for all of the different use cases people have come up with... without manually going through each and every page and then scrolling to see if one of my blocks is used or not. Some sites have hundreds of pages and posts. I would like to make it a more efficient process to find just the pages and posts where a custom block is used.

Comment: One can e.g. use the general search in the wp-admin backend to find text within the post content of pages or posts e.g. `wp:paragraph` for paragraph blocks to match part of the saved html paragraph structure.

Comment: You can check out the https://wordpress.org/plugins/find-my-blocks/

Comment: Thank you, @birgire. The built-in search using the "wp:" prefix works well to find which posts contain my blocks. It is good to know the admin search has this capability.

Comment: Thank you @Will for the recommendation. Unfortunately the "Find My Blocks" plugin didn't work for me. It got stuck on a perpetual loading screen. I will have to do some troubleshooting to find out why it isn't loading properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### General block name search

One can e.g. use the general search in the `/wp-admin` backend to find some text within the post's content that stores the blocks:

[image]

We can search for a prefixed block name `wp:my-plugin/my-block` within the posts:

```
example.com/wp-admin/edit.php
?s=wp:my-plugin%2Fmy-block%20&post_type=post
```

where we have an extra space (url encoded as `%20`and / as `%2F`) after the block's name, as the first part of it would be stored as `<!-- wp:my-plugin/my-block -->` or with attributes `<!-- wp:my-plugin/my-block {...} -->` in the post's content.

The front-end search works as well, but without the post type filtering as in the backend (unless adjusted with a plugin):

```
example.com
?s=wp:my-plugin%2Fmy-block%20
```

This block search might not be 100% accurate (e.g. if you blog about block names) but it might give you a good enough estimate in most cases.

### **More accurate searching**

We note that searching for `<!-- wp:my-plugin/my-block`  with:

```
example.com
?s=<%21--%20wp:my-plugin%2Fmy-block%20
```

will be split up in two words in the generated SQL:

```
WHERE 1=1
AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%<!--%')
OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%<!--%')
OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%<!--%'))
AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%wp:my-plugin/my-block %')
OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%wp:my-plugin/my-block %')
OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%wp:my-plugin/my-block %')))
...
```

but we can avoid it with the `sentence` parameter:

```
example.com
?s=<%21--%20wp:my-plugin%2Fmy-block&sentence=1
```

and get a search query like:

```
WHERE 1=1
AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%<!-- wp:my-plugin/my-block %')
OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%<!-- wp:my-plugin/my-block %')
OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%<!-- wp:my-plugin/my-block %')))
...
```

### With code

Alternatively we could use a custom `WP_Query` search like:

```
WP_Query( array( 
    's'         => '<!-- wp:my-plugin/my-block ', 
    'sentence'  => 1, 
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page' ),
) );
```

or run `has_block( 'my-plugin/my-block', $post_content )` on all the relevant post content for the given block name or use `parse_blocks( $post_content )` if you need more info from it.

### Reusable blocks

We should note that reusable blocks are stored like:

```
<!-- wp:block {"ref":23495} /-->
```

in the post's content, so we might look into the `wp_block` post type that stores it:

```
example.com/wp-admin/edit.php
?s=<%21--%20wp:my-plugin%2Fmy-block%20&post_status=all&post_type=wp_block&sentence=1
```

### Simple Block Type Search Plugin

To make things easier I've created a plugin that adds a dropdown filter for registered block types, under each list table in the admin:

[image]

to simplify the search that is automatically added when filtering:

[image]

Create a plugin file and activate:

```
<?php 
/* Plugin Name: Simple Block Type Search
 * Plugin URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/392175/26350 
 */
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'simple_block_type_search', 10, 2 );

function simple_block_type_search ( $post_type, $which ) {
    if ( ! use_block_editor_for_post_type ( $post_type ) ) {
        return;
    } 
    $block_types = \WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance()->get_all_registered();
    $options = array_reduce( $block_types, function( $options, $block_type ) {
        $val = '!-- wp:' . str_replace( 'core/', '', $block_type->name ) . ' ';
        return $options . sprintf ( '<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>',
            esc_attr( $val ),
            selected( get_query_var( 's' ), $val, false ),
            esc_html( $block_type->name )
        );
    }, '' );
    printf ( '<select name="s"><option value="">%s</option>%s</select>
              <input type="hidden" name="sentence" value="1"/>', 
         esc_html__( 'Block Type Search', 'simple_block_type_search' ),
         $options            
    );
}
```

To get all registered block types, we [used](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_block_type_registry/get_all_registered/):

```
\WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance()->get_all_registered()
```

and to only display the dropdown on supported post types we [used](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/use_block_editor_for_post_type/):

```
use_block_editor_for_post_type()
```

Here we used the built-in search feature and the user interface of the admin backend. That's why the plugin is so few lines of code.

Comment: ps: I added a slightly updated version [here](https://xlino.com/projects/simple-block-type-search-plugin/).

Comment: What a useful plugin! Great job!

Comment: @Rvervuurt Thanks glad to hear it helps

Comment: commenting again because I suddenly found a bug in this solution: normal searching within the Wordpress admin stops working. The `s`-attribute in the URL is empty when I search in my pages. Any idea how to fix this? If I filter by blocks used, it works fine and the block is added to the `s`-attribute.

Comment: @Rvervuurt thanks for noticing. The solution would be to change the name parameter of the custom select box and add a `pre_get_posts` hook to append that select box value to the default main query search parameter `s`. Hopefully I can update in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm WordPress user and sometimes I install packs of blocks that come with some block similar to core blocks.

When I try to find where some blocks have been used, I do it with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/find-my-blocks/